# How to embed form in in sonata admin-generator of symfony2 bundle

Tags: symfony, admin, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

I am using sonata-admin generator for one of my project.

I want to create a form which contains fields from two tables User and User_add.

My tables are like this:

USER:  id,name,age,login_id,pwd,create_at,updated_at
USER_ADD: id,user_id(FK from user),add_type,street,city,state,country,pin.

Now I want a single form so that, I should be able to insert data for both user as well as user_add using sonata admin generator.

Please suggest me some link if, I can get answer of this doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=38120, it describes doctrine one-to-one relation between item and itemDetail and how to use sonata_type_admin to have a possibility to create itemDetail from item form.